# Why is my CGImage changing colors when exporting through AVAssetExportSession?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-image, cgimage, avassetexportsession

I'm overlaying a CGImage on a video through AVMutableComposition and that works great (see Screenshot A below). The problem is when I export the video with AVAssetExportSession, I get some weird outlines and colors (see Screenshot B). How do I export this video retaining the proper colors of the CGImage and without the odd yellow/black outlines?

Here's the code I'm using to export:

```
func saveVideo(composition: AVMutableComposition, vidComp: AVMutableVideoComposition, audioMix: AVMutableAudioMix) {
    let preset = "AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080"
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: preset) else {
        return
    }

    let videoSize: CGSize = vidComp.renderSize

    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.isGeometryFlipped = true
    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)

    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)


    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Fire1", ofType: "mov")!)
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
    generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero

    do {
        let cgImg = try generator.copyCGImage(at: CMTime(seconds: 0.5, preferredTimescale: 1000), actualTime: nil)
        let imgLayer = CALayer()
        imgLayer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect
        imgLayer.contents = cgImg
        imgLayer.frame = parentLayer.bounds
        parentLayer.addSublayer(imgLayer)
    } catch {
        print("No thumbnail")
    }

    vidComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

    exportSession.videoComposition = vidComp
    exportSession.audioMix = audioMix
    exportSession.outputURL = self.uniqueURLForSave()
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        switch exportSession.status {
        case .completed:
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(exportSession.outputURL!.relativePath, self, nil, nil)
        default:
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot A (proper image):
[image]

Screenshot B (faulty image with yellow and black outlines):
[image]

Comment: How did you get the correct image?

Comment: I have a thumbnail from the After Effects project. It's the same asset but instead of a video I got an image.